# Lua string.match utf - asking for spanish character - getting half portuguese

Tags: utf-8, lua, pattern-matching

Hi the following code in Lua:

```
letters = "Vocéá"
print(string.match("¡Você","["..letters.."]+"))
```

returns:

```
�Voc�
```

if I replace é with regular e and get rid of á then I get "Voc". seems that á interferes with ¡, and é with ê. Could it be that they share a byte in common?
I am not an expert in encoding, but these are the utf16 values,utf8 binaries:

```
á(feff00e1) 1100 0011 1010 0001
¡(feff00a1) 1100 0010 1010 0001
ê(feff00ea) 1100 0011 1010 1010
é(feff00e9) 1100 0011 1010 1001
```

How am I to ignore the portuguese character & the "¡" (and many others I am not aware of)?

Maybe this is not the best approach anyways. I am trying to build a spanish tokenizer. I am surprised though that the match function returns a question mark from a character that is not included in my match list.

Comment: lua's string functions are not utf-8 aware. They are just bytes. So that match isn't doing what you expect. lua 5.3 has a utf8 library though. So the problem is that you are splitting characters in half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters and bytes are two different things. Characters can be encoded in bytes in various ways, using different [encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). One possible encoding is UTF-8. Unfortunately Lua's string.match doesn't know almost anything about  charactes and encodings, it only works with bytes.

So your script is not looking for the "V", "c", "o", "á", "é" characters, but for the "\x56", "\x63", "\x6F", "\xA1", "\xA9", "\xC3" bytes.